# Does this definition say what I want it to?

Tags: definition, quantifiers

I don't have a real background in math but I should still be able to define stuff in my MSc thesis, although the thesis does not involve a lot of math.

I want to define an object $o$'s spatiotemporal routine $R_{o}$ as a set of frequently visited places $p_{i}(t)$ by this object. The visits to each place are dependent on time, i.e. (mostly) visited during certain times (of the day, of the week, does not really matter). I cannot and don't want to define "frequent" yet, thus I somehow want to say that the frequency of visits should be above a threshold $\alpha$.
I came up with this definition:

$$R_{o} = \left\{p_{1}(t),p_{2}(t),p_{i}(t),...,p_{n}(t)|\forall p_{i}: freq(p_{i}) \geq \alpha\right\}$$

My questions: 1. Is this a correct use of the $\forall$ quantifier? It should mean that the frequency criterion should apply to ALL places which are contained in the set. 
2. Is there another way to define frequency than to use the ugly $freq()$?

Maybe somebody can come up with a better, more elegant, or more "professional" definition, I've never done that before but it shouldn't be too difficult, right?

Comment: What exactly is $p_i(t)$? Is it the number of total visits to the place $i$ at time $t$? Or is it the mean of the visits to place $i$ at the daytime $i$? What does the function $frec$ do exactly? The quantifier is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you want to say
$$R_o=\{\,p(t)\mid \operatorname{freq}(p(t))\ge \alpha\,\}$$

Comment: Very elegant, thank you. But what about the $freq()$ function, could I express this more mathematically? Like $|p(t)| \geq \alpha$ --- that would mean that *all* the $p$'s together are frequent and not what I want, right?